# How to use kotlin byteArray in IOS from shared KMM package

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

We're facing an issue when trying to utilize a Kotlin byteArray, which isn't supported directly in SwiftUI, to load an image stored in the database. Can anyone provide guidance on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import kotlinx.cinterop.BetaInteropApi
import kotlinx.cinterop.ExperimentalForeignApi
import kotlinx.cinterop.addressOf
import kotlinx.cinterop.allocArrayOf
import kotlinx.cinterop.memScoped
import kotlinx.cinterop.usePinned
import platform.Foundation.NSData
import platform.Foundation.create
import platform.posix.memcpy

@OptIn(ExperimentalForeignApi::class)
fun NSData.toByteArray(): ByteArray {
    return ByteArray(length.toInt()).apply {
        usePinned {
            memcpy(it.addressOf(0), bytes, length)
        }
    }
}

@BetaInteropApi
@OptIn(ExperimentalForeignApi::class)
fun ByteArray.toNSData(): NSData = memScoped {
    NSData.create(bytes = allocArrayOf(this@toNSData), length = this@toNSData.size.toULong())
}
```